# Can someone explain the 6 alternative volatility measures?

Tags: volatility

I'm reading this:
https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/files/a_estimation_of_security_price.pdf

and am a bit confused as to why the "classical equation" on page 3 does not divide by n-1 nor use the log prices.  I'm assuming C is just the closing price itself.

Thank!

Comment: Please paste the equation in to the questions, as link will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the document carefully:

> Thus in the geometric case,  "price"  would  mean  "logarithm  of 
>   original price",  and  "volatility"  would  mean  "variance  of  the 
>   logarithm  of original prices"

so the difference is really the log-return.

Now, the formula you are referring to is the estimator of the variance *on one particular day* given that only daily returns are observed. What you have in mind is the sample volatility estimated from many returns.